# How to retrieve all wikipedia Infobox templates

Tags: java, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

Here lists all infobox templates in wikipedia. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:List_of_infoboxes

Is there a way or method that can retrieve all the inforbox templates listed in the page? I want to use each of the infobx template to retrieve pages from.

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Infobox_templates + https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Categorymembers

If you want to retrive the infobox templates *content*, use Wikidata or dbpedia.org.